# JSON - Can't send headers after the are sent

Tags: node.js

Sometimes, when I run this code, it I get the following error.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

```
User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.json({
   success: false,
   message: "Unknown error."
  });
 }

 if (user != undefined) {
  res.json({
   success: true,
   message: "User exists."
  });
 }
 else {
  res.json({
   success: true,
   message: "User does not exist."
  });
 }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code continues to run even if there is a mongoose error, causing your app to try to respond to the request twice. Just add a return to after the json response. Like so:

```
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Unknown error."
    });
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the DB will respond twice when there is an error. To end the response, just return;

```
if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    response.json({
        success: false,
        message: "An error occurred."
    });
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if first condition true , then application not go any other condition to send response

```
 else if (user != undefined) {
```